# How to update the data in Todo List using Sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anyone please send the code for updating the data using sqlite for todolist app. I use the 4 parts of "Creating a ToDo List using Sqlite" from Google. But in that , when i enter the data it takes and changed. But, when i build again it shows previous data which i was entered in the insert command. It doesn't saved permenantly. Please refer the code which is at Google.

And pls help me to update the data.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The New Todo that you add in the application does not get saved anywhere in the database instead there is a Static tuple (a new record) which is inserted

```
"INSERT INTO todo (text,priority,complete) VALUES('New Todo','3','0')"
```

If you wish to permanently save the new Todo then you will have to write a function that separately adds the new data or updates the previous one (The dummy row that was added). You can set this functionality using a done button or when user navigates back to the main view (RootView).
All you need to do is use an update query to save the data in this particular example.

Comment: Mark it as an answer if it solves your query  else let me know if you need any further explanations or any link which can be more explanatory .

Comment: ya sure i need a link to add, save and update the data .....  can u pls send the link regarding ToDo List App...

Comment: you can refer to http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-adding-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I'm not going to download some google code just to check this for you.

Provide your code and explain exactly what this issue is. Help us to help you.

At the least provide a link for the google code so those who want to download can.

Comment: Hii This is the link       http://jainmarket.blogspot.com/2009/05/creating-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-4.html     Thanks